# JQuery Slider Initialize in Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slider

I am using the JQuery slider, and it loads fine in my header. I suppose it is being initialed with the following code:

```
$(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
orientation: "horizontal",
range: "min",
min: 0,
max: 100,
value: 60,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
}
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
$( ".selector" ).on( "slidecreate", function( event, ui ) {
} );
```

I am calling an Ajax function that responds with another JQuery slider using the tag

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Here is the Ajax function:

```
<!-- Ajax Function for removing an users favorites-->
function ShowFavoritesAjax(url,cfunc,userID)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("user_id=" + userID);
}


function ShowFavorites(userID)
{
ShowFavoritesAjax("ajaxPHP/users/ajaxShowFavorites.php",function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("userFav").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
    } else { 
    document.getElementById("userFav").innerHTML='<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif">';
   }
  },userID,bandID);
}
```

So I am guessing that I need to "initialize the Slider" in one of my Ajax functions. So I tried this by modifying the return as so: (I just pasted the initialize function in it's entirety right before the response text is displayed)

```
function ShowFavorites(userID)
{
ShowFavoritesAjax("ajaxPHP/users/ajaxShowFavorites.php",function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
 $(function() {
$( "#slider" ).slider({
orientation: "horizontal",
range: "min",
min: 0,
max: 100,
value: 60,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
$( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
}
});
$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );
});
$( ".selector" ).on( "slidecreate", function( event, ui ) {
} );
    document.getElementById("userFav").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
    } else { 
    document.getElementById("userFav").innerHTML='<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif">';
   }
  },userID);
}
```

If anyone can spot my problem and has a fix I would really be grateful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function ShowFavorites(userID)
{
   ShowFavoritesAjax("ajaxPHP/users/ajaxShowFavorites.php",function()
   {
         if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
             document.getElementById("userFav").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText; 
                $( "#slider" ).slider({
                    orientation: "horizontal",
                    range: "min",
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    value: 60,
                    slide: function( event, ui ) {
                          $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
                  });

              $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" ) );

              $( ".selector" ).on( "slidecreate", function( event, ui ) {
              });
            } else { 
               document.getElementById("userFav").innerHTML='<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif">';
           }
  },userID);
}
```

What I have changed in this code:

- move the line `document.getElementById("userFav").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` to be executed first.
- Remove the `$(function() {`

Reasons:

- `$(function() {` fires when document is ready (not in this case).
- When you execute your code like $.slider, the html is not inserted into the document yet => so you have to reverse the order.

Comment: Thanks Khanh, I appreciate your explanation to shed some light on how the JQuery works. I am still not getting it to work, but not giving up.

Comment: @CameronMacfarlane: What I've pointed out here are problems you should consider, maybe there are other issues. It's difficult for me to know because there maybe other issues that are not in this code. Hope you make it work soon. Happy coding

Comment: @CameronMacfarlane: congratulations.